# DjangoFilters-Filtering users from model

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django-Filters I make a dinamic filter, I'm trying to filter the users from "paciente" in the model "Medicard_rd". I figure how to filter the users from the other model "perfil". I put my models, views, and filters.py files.

I need help, i can't figure the views.py queryset i have to use to filter those users in "Medicard_rd", and when i filter the users i want to show the fields "Titulo","hospital",etc. in the page. HELP me please.

Models.py (the two models "Medicard_rd" and "perfil"
[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv4BG.png)

Filters.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

import django_filters

class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:

    model = User

    fields = ['username', ]# 'first_name', 'last_name', ]
```

Views.py[Views.p, like i said i figure only the "perfil" query model for users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9ltD.png)

Comment: Paste code instead of images and fix your indentation, please.

Comment: In your views.py file you use relative imports.  You should know that best practice is to use only absolute imports.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.  Try reformulating the question, and you'll get more responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Medicard_rdFilter(FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Medicard_rd
        fields = {
            'paciente': ['exact', 'isnull'],
            'paciente__username': ['icontains'],
        }
```

use this filter to get Medicard_rd queryset by paciente__username,use like `www.example.com/Medicard_rd/?paciente__username__icontains=example`,then list Medicard_rd queryset,your can get user、Titulo、hospital at same time.is this fit what your want?If not,say clearer about what you're trying to achieve.